# JavaScript ungroup data in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to flatten the below data structure, I feel like there must be a good way fo doing this without manually iterating through each element to manually build it.

```
[{
    group: 'abc',
    data: [{
       name: 'John',
       age: 10
    }, {
       name: 'Alice',
       age: 15
    }]
}, {
    group: 'def',
    data: [{
       name: 'Scott',
       age: 20
    }, {
       name: 'Tamar',
       age: 25
    }]
}]
```

and I wanted it to be something like this instead (so the group is alongside the data):

```
[{
   group: 'abc',
   name: 'John',
   age: 10
}, {
   group: 'abc',
   name: 'Alice',
   age: 15
}, {
   group: 'def',
   name: 'Scott',
   age: 20
}, {
   group: 'def',
   name: 'Tamar',
   age: 25
}]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const a = [
  {group: 'abc', data: [{name: 'John', age: 10}, {name: 'Alice', age: 15}]},
  {group: 'def', data: [{name: 'Scott', age: 20}, {name: 'Tamar', age: 25}]}
];

const flat = a.flatMap(({group, data}) => data.map(o => Object.assign({group}, o)));
console.log(flat)

// Unmodified original Array:
console.log(a)
```

- [MDN Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [MDN Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [MDN Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: You are mutating the original objects. Since you are not using the array created by `Array.map()`, use `Array.forEach()` instead.

Comment: @OriDrori Seems like a late hour, thanks for the extra pair of eyes. Improved to account

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the array with `Array.flatMap()`, then map each group, and construct the new objects using object spread:

```js
const arr = [{"group":"abc","data":[{"name":"John","age":10},{"name":"Alice","age":15}]},{"group":"def","data":[{"name":"Scott","age":20},{"name":"Tamar","age":25}]}]

const result = arr.flatMap(({ group, data }) => data.map(o => ({ group, ...o })))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array#reduce` would be helpful.

```js
const a = [{group:'abc',data:[{name:'John',age:10},{name:'Alice',age:15}]},{group:'def',data:[{name:'Scott',age:20},{name:'Tamar',age:25}]}];

const r = a.reduce((s, { group, data }) =>
   (data.forEach((o) => s.push({ ...o, group })), s), []);

console.log(r);
```