# Unnest array of objects contained in object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the structure of my data. An array of shipments containing array of items
I need to have an array with entries for each shipment-item and I need to do this with javascript

```
[
    {
        "shipmentNumber":12345678,
        "items":[
            {
                "productId":80000000000001,
                "price":100,
                "quantity":1
            },
            {
                "productId":80000000000002,
                "price":80,
                "quantity":1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "shipmentNumber":89675645,
        "items":[
            {
                "productId":80000000000003,
                "price":100,
                "quantity":1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

**N.B.:** The main array containing shipments has 5000+ elements

```
[
    {
        "shipmentNumber":12345678,
        "items": {
                "productId":80000000000001,
                "price":100,
                "quantity":1
            }
    },
    {
        "shipmentNumber":12345678,
        "items":
            {
                "productId":80000000000002,
                "price":80,
                "quantity":1
            }
    },
    {
        "shipmentNumber":89675645,
        "items":
            {
                "productId":80000000000003,
                "price":100,
                "quantity":1
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: You forgot to add a [mcve] of what you tried. Please read [ask], and since you missed it — take a [tour]. Then [edit] to improve your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript ungroup data in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083417/javascript-ungroup-data-in-object)

Answer (score 2):

A combination `flatMap/map` should do the trick:

```
result = a.flatMap(
    s => s.items.map(
        item => ({shipmentNumber: s.shipmentNumber, item})
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to map the needed data in each nested array,and `.flatMap()` method to flatten the result arrays into the single array.

```js
const shipments = [
  {
    "shipmentNumber":12345678,
    "items":[
      {
        "productId":80000000000001,
        "price":100,
        "quantity":1
      },
      {
        "productId":80000000000002,
        "price":80,
        "quantity":1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "shipmentNumber":89675645,
    "items":[
      {
        "productId":80000000000003,
        "price":100,
        "quantity":1
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result = shipments.flatMap(shipment =>
  shipment.items.map(item => ({
    shipmentNumber: shipment.shipmentNumber,
    item: item
  }))
);

console.log(result);
```